# Hadoop Namenode not accessible

Tags: apache, hadoop

So I have been trying to setup a hadoop cluster on a private network and I have come across a strange problem.

My datanodes and namenode are all running but the datanodes cannot connect to the namenode.

I have noticed in the logs that the namenode is starting on

system1/192.168.100.11:9000

and datanodes are searching for

192.168.100.11:9000

My configuration only has:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://192.168.100.11:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas as to why hadoop is trying to work this way?

Comment: Have you turned off the firewall on the nodes or allow firewall to allow traffic hadoop specific ports ?

Comment: I have checked on that and iptables isn't appearing to block anything or filter anything. All of the ports appear to be open locally.